# HTML Radio Button

Tags: javascript, html

I have typed the following code in Front Page and it gives error in displaying Radio Button Values (as undefined):

```js
function f1() {
        var fn = document.frm.T1.value;
        var ln = document.frm.T2.value;
        var ad = document.frm.S1.value;
        var sex = document.frm.R1.value;
        var nat = document.frm.D1.value;
        var typ = document.frm.R2.value;
        var typ1 = document.frm.C1.value;
        var typ2 = document.frm.C2.value;
        var typ3 = document.frm.C3.value;
        var budg = document.frm.R3.value;
        var mail = document.frm.T5.value;
        var mob = document.frm.T3.value;
        var resi = document.frm.T4.value;
        var city = document.frm.D2.value;
        var com = document.frm.S2.value;

        document.write("Welcome Dear " + fn + " " + ln + "<br>" + "Your Residential Address is " + ad + " and you are " + nat + " National " + "<br>" + "You are looking to " + typ + " the property " +
            " and you are interested in " + typ1 + " " + typ2 + " " + typ3 + " Flat." + "<br>" + " Your estimated budget is INR " + budg + "<br>" +
            " You will be informed using your e-mail address " + mail + " You will be contacted on your Mobile Number " + mob + " or Residence Number " + resi + "<br>" +
            " You are looking for the property in " + city + " City" + " You have following comments " + "<br>" + com);
    }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left"><font face="Berlin Sans FB Demi" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </font>
</p>
<p align="center"><span style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <font face="Berlin Sans FB Demi">Kindly Fill - Up the details given below and 
    out Customer Support Team will contact you shortly!</font></span>
</p>
<p align="left"><font face="Berlin Sans FB Demi" color="#FFFFFF">
    </font>
</p>
<form method="POST" name="frm" action="--WEBBOT-SELF--">
    <!--webbot bot="SaveResults" U-File="../_private/form_results.csv" S-Format="TEXT/CSV" S-Label-Fields="TRUE" startspan -->
    <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="VTI-GROUP" VALUE="0">
    <!--webbot bot="SaveResults" i-checksum="43374" endspan -->
    <div align="left">
        <table border="1" width="39%">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <p align="center"><b><font color="#FFFF00">INQUIRY FORM</font></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>First Name</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="T1" size="25">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Last Name</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="T2" size="25">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Postal Address</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="2" name="S1" cols="20"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Gender</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="MALE" name="R1"><font color="#FFFFFF">MALE
        </font>
                    <input type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="R1"><font color="#FFFFFF"> 
        FEMALE</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Nationality</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select size="1" name="D1">
                        <option selected value="Indian">INDIAN</option>
                        <option value="British">BRITISH</option>
                        <option value="Canadian">CANADIAN</option>
                        <option value="Chinese">CHINESE</option>
                        <option value="Japanese">JAPANESE</option>
                        <option value="GCC">MID EASTERN</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Looking For</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="R2" value="Buy" id="1"><font color="#FFFFFF">BUY
        <input type="radio"     name="R2" value="Lease">LEASE</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Type</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="1 BHK"><font color="#FFFFFF">1 
        BHK <input type="checkbox" name="C2" value="2 BHK">2 BHK
        <input type="checkbox" name="C3" value="3 BHK">3 BHK</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Budget</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="R3" value="20-30 Lakhs"><font color="#FFFFFF">20-30 
        LAKHS</font>
                    <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="R3" value="40-60 Lakhs"><font color="#FFFFFF">40-60 
        LAKHS</font>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="R3" value="MORE 
        THAN 60 LAKHS"><font color="#FFFFFF">MORE 
        THAN 60 LAKHS</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF">E-Mail ID</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="T5" size="20">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF">Phone Number</font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="T3" size="20">
                    <font color="#FFFFFF">Mob</font>
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="T4" size="20"><font color="#FFFFFF"> 
        Res</font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Preferred City</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select size="1" name="D2">
                        <option selected value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>
                        <option value="Bangalore">BANGALORE</option>
                        <option value="Pune">PUNE</option>
                        <option value="Ahmedabad">AHMEDABAD</option>
                        <option value="Kochi">KOCHI</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Comments</b></font>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="2" name="S2" cols="20"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Inquire" name="B1" onclick="f1()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2">
    </p>
</form>

<p align="center">
    <a href="Home.htm">
        <img border="0" src="home_1.png" width="75" height="72">
    </a>
</p>
```

Rest of the things are working except radio buttons. Kindly help with a solution for the same. Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have `sex` or `typ` in the `document.write()`. The budget radio button works because you write `budg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
  What color do you prefer?<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="red">Red<br>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" id="blue">Blue
</form>

<button onclick="check()">Check "Red"</button>
<button onclick="uncheck()">Uncheck "Red"</button>

<script>
function check() {
    document.getElementById("red").checked = true;
}
function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("red").checked = false;
}
</script>
```

link:-http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

All Radio Buttons has the same name. So you have to select the checked radio button by using `document.querySelector('input[name=R1]:checked').value`. I have even checked for unselected checkbox value as "Empty"

```js
function f1() {
  var fn = document.frm.T1.value;
  var ln = document.frm.T2.value;
  var ad = document.frm.S1.value;
  var sex = document.frm.R1.value;
  var nat = document.frm.D1.value;
  var typ = document.frm.R2.value;
  var typ1 = document.frm.C1.value;
  var typ2 = document.frm.C2.value;
  var typ3 = document.frm.C3.value;
  var budg = document.frm.R3.value;
  var mail = document.frm.T5.value;
  var mob = document.frm.T3.value;
  var resi = document.frm.T4.value;
  var city = document.frm.D2.value;
  var com = document.frm.S2.value;

  document.write("Welcome Dear " + fn + " " + ln + "<br/>" + "Your Sex is " + ((document.querySelector('input[name=R1]:checked'))?document.querySelector('input[name=R1]:checked').value:"Empty") + "<br/>" + "Your Residential Address is " + ad + " and you are " + nat + " National " + "<br>" + "You are looking to " + typ + " the property " +
    " and you are interested in " + typ1 + " " + typ2 + " " + typ3 + " Flat." + "<br>" + " Your estimated budget is INR " + budg + "<br>" +
    " You will be informed using your e-mail address " + mail + " You will be contacted on your Mobile Number " + mob + " or Residence Number " + resi + "<br>" +
    " You are looking for the property in " + city + " City" + " You have following comments " + "<br>" + com);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
  }
```

```html
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<p align="left"><font face="Berlin Sans FB Demi" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </font>
</p>
<p align="center"><span style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
    <font face="Berlin Sans FB Demi">Kindly Fill - Up the details given below and 
    out Customer Support Team will contact you shortly!</font></span>
</p>
<p align="left"><font face="Berlin Sans FB Demi" color="#FFFFFF">
    </font>
</p>
<form method="POST" name="frm" action="--WEBBOT-SELF--">
  <!--webbot bot="SaveResults" U-File="../_private/form_results.csv" S-Format="TEXT/CSV" S-Label-Fields="TRUE" startspan -->
  <input TYPE="hidden" NAME="VTI-GROUP" VALUE="0">
  <!--webbot bot="SaveResults" i-checksum="43374" endspan -->
  <div align="left">
    <table border="1" width="39%">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <p align="center"><b><font color="#FFFF00">INQUIRY FORM</font></b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>First Name</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="T1" size="25">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Last Name</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="T2" size="25">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Postal Address</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="2" name="S1" cols="20"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Gender</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" value="MALE" name="R1"><font color="#FFFFFF">MALE
        </font>
          <input type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="R1"><font color="#FFFFFF"> 
        FEMALE</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Nationality</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select size="1" name="D1">
            <option selected value="Indian">INDIAN</option>
            <option value="British">BRITISH</option>
            <option value="Canadian">CANADIAN</option>
            <option value="Chinese">CHINESE</option>
            <option value="Japanese">JAPANESE</option>
            <option value="GCC">MID EASTERN</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Looking For</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="R2" value="Buy" id="1"><font color="#FFFFFF">BUY
        <input type="radio"     name="R2" value="Lease">LEASE</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Type</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="1 BHK"><font color="#FFFFFF">1 
        BHK <input type="checkbox" name="C2" value="2 BHK">2 BHK
        <input type="checkbox" name="C3" value="3 BHK">3 BHK</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Budget</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="R3" value="20-30 Lakhs"><font color="#FFFFFF">20-30 
        LAKHS</font>
          <p>
            <input type="radio" name="R3" value="40-60 Lakhs"><font color="#FFFFFF">40-60 
        LAKHS</font>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="radio" name="R3" value="MORE 
        THAN 60 LAKHS"><font color="#FFFFFF">MORE 
        THAN 60 LAKHS</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF">E-Mail ID</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="T5" size="20">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF">Phone Number</font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="T3" size="20">
          <font color="#FFFFFF">Mob</font>
          <p>
            <input type="text" name="T4" size="20"><font color="#FFFFFF"> 
        Res</font>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Preferred City</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select size="1" name="D2">
            <option selected value="Mumbai">MUMBAI</option>
            <option value="Bangalore">BANGALORE</option>
            <option value="Pune">PUNE</option>
            <option value="Ahmedabad">AHMEDABAD</option>
            <option value="Kochi">KOCHI</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="147"><font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Comments</b></font>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea rows="2" name="S2" cols="20"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Inquire" name="B1" onclick="f1()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="B2">
  </p>
</form>

<p align="center">
  <a href="Home.htm">
    <img border="0" src="home_1.png" width="75" height="72">
  </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either by jQuery or jsvascript

1. In jQuery use `$('input[name="R1"]:checked').val();` here R1 is your checkbox name
2. In javascript get the dom elements by name and loop through the elements to get the selection.

I have attached a sample code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function ChangeSelection() {
            //Using Jquery
            var selection = $('input[name="R1"]:checked').val();
            console.log("jQuery Result - " + selection);

            //Javascript
            var radios = document.getElementsByName('R1');
            for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
                if (radios[i].checked) {
                    //Selected Radio
                    selection = radios[i].value;
                    // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log("JavaScript Result - " + selection);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" value="MALE" name="R1" onclick="ChangeSelection()"><font>MALE</font>
    <input type="radio" value="FEMALE" name="R1" onclick="ChangeSelection()"><font>FEMALE</font>
</body>

</html>
```